# Signed int array typecast C#

Tags: c#, arrays, casting, int, signed

When I run the following code:

```
public int[] finalResult = new int[dimension];
public float[] calculatedValue = new float[dimension];
.....
.....
finalResult[i] = (int) Math.Floor(calculatedValue[i]);
Console.WriteLine( "calculated:" + calculatedValue[i] 
    +  " final:" + finalResult[i] 
    + "  test: " +(int) Math.Floor(calculatedValue[i]));
```

The output is:

> calculated:-0.02043936 final:0 test:-1

Why is "final" different from "test" when they are generated from exactly the same code? Which one is wrong, and why?

even simpler, and smaller fragment

```
finalResult[i]=(int)Math.Floor(-3.0002);
Console.WriteLine( "final: "+ finalResult[i]+ " test:" +(int)Math.Floor(-3.0002));
```

**output**
final:0 test:-4

**The remaining of the code is irrevelant as below proves**
I tried the following lastly,

```
public int[] junkArray = new int[dimension];
junkArray[i]=(int)Math.Floor(-3.0002);  //Junk Array is only assigned here in whole code
Console.WriteLine( "final: "+ (int) junkArray[i]+ " test:" +(int)Math.Floor(-3.0002));
```

I get output as final:0 test:-4

Comment: @Servy I'm assuming thats `-0.02043936` but, I'm not sure how the arrays are relevant to the question.

Comment: When I add something like ' finalResult[i] = -9; ' between finalResult[i] and Console.Writeline( "calculated:") ... , the output gives me final=-9 (which is correct), so I think omitted code is not relevant.

Comment: Try moving your `finalResult[i]` assignment to inside your `Console.WriteLine()` and see what you get.

Comment: Could you please post a *complete* code snippet that we can run to demonstrate this problem.  I have attempted to replicate your results but I cannot.  Also, what version of .NET are you using?

Comment: @user1164501 I just ran `int num = (int)Math.Floor(-3.0002);  Console.WriteLine("final: " + num + " test:" + (int)Math.Floor(-3.0002));` and got `final: -4 test:-4`.

Comment: I have tested your "simpler, and smaller fragment", and `final:-4, test:-4` were my results.  As Servy asked, if you post more of the code, we can help you better.

Comment: Can it happen that  you declare `finalResult` twice one public field one in a method, and use it in two different methods?

Comment: More code is never irrelevant.  I tested your last edit, and still received `final: -4 test:-4`  My suggestion is to step through your code, and see if `finalResult[i]` is being assigned somewhere else before you're outputting it.

Comment: Kevin, did you look at my last addition? I created   junkArrary and its only get assigned once.

Comment: @user1164501: Did you read my last comment?  I tested that, and still got `final: -4 test: -4`.

Comment: Are all of us and the compiler wrong, or, are you missing somthing you aren't telling us?

Comment: You really need to give us code that we can actually run. If I create a new console application and plug your code into the Main() method, it won't compile. I have to adapt it before it will compile, and that immediately means that the code I'm running *is not what you're running*, which drastically reduces the usefulness of our feedback. You're still sat there saying "my code doesn't work" and we're still sat here saying "our code does work" and we're not getting anywhere.

Comment: Suggestion: please change the line in your actual program that corresponds to "junkArray[i]=(int)Math.Floor(-3.0002);" to "junkArray[i]=7" and then run your program. If the output lists "final:7", then you have indeed found some obscure bug with Math.Floor on your given platform & framework version. If the output still lists "final:0", though, then you're doing something wrong elsewhere and you need to show us more code before we can help.

Comment: Well I had tried that first, and it was in my first edit. I have no idea but the moderator deleted that edit. So that was correct, I was getting final:7. But its not a bug either. Definitely the code has some bugs, not Math.Floor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I test the code

```
var final = new int[1];
var calc = new[] { -0.02043936f };
final[0] = (int)Math.Floor(calc[0]);

Console.WriteLine(
    "calc:{0} final:{1} test:{2}",
    calc[0],
    final[0],
    (int)Math.Floor(calc[0]));
```

unsuprisingly I get the output

> calc:-0.02043936 final:-1 test:-1

So, something else is wrong with your code.

Comment: Agreed, I put together similar testcase code and can't reproduce the questioner's results either. For the examples provided I get output of "calc:-0.02043936 final:-1 test:-1" and "calc:-3.0002 final:-4 test:-4" respectively.

Comment: Well, could you look at my last edit, where I put junkArray. Clearly, if there is any mistake in the code, that must be in those 3 lines, if not something else.

Comment: Nothing looks any different in your last edit. I can't test it without adapting it, since what you've posted isn't a compilable program - it's not a method body since you have a public field declaration there, and the given code doesn't declare or initialise dimension or i. There's little more that can be gleaned from that example as a result, so could you put together a testcase that is actually complete and runnable for us to look at?

Comment: I tried Jodrell's code, I get correct result (same as Jodrell's output).

Comment: I tried,  `public int[] junkArray = new int[10];                  junkArray[0]=(int)Math.Floor(-5.0002);`  still same, wrong output.

Comment: Those two lines can't possibly be together. The first line is a field declaration, which is legal at the class level but not inside a method/property. The second line is an assignment which is *not* legal at the class level but *is* legal inside a method/property. Thus, the two lines came from different places, and you're plucking out fragments of code to show us. The problem with this is that the chances are your error is sneaking in from a line you haven't shown us yet.

Comment: yes you are right, I had put it to the class declaration. Anyway, I was suspicious of a problem with the compiler, since Jodrell's code went fine, I am convinced it should be something in my code

Comment: Please see my latest comment on the question itself. Let's rule out Math.Floor entirely by just assigning a known value, such as 7, and see what results get printed out. If it's 7, you've found a bizarre and obscure bug with Math.Floor on your platform/framework. If it's 0, then it's nothing to do with Math.Floor and you're doing something wrong elsewhere. You could, for example, have a declaration of a junkArray variable in a method body that's shadowing the junkArray field declaration, writing your results to the field but then reading from the variable that's still in its default state.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I think is actually happening. Bear in mind that I'm making assumptions here, since the code you've provided doesn't compile and when I try to adapt it I always get the correct results that I'd expect. I've thus tried to think of ways to produce the results you're getting by making a deliberate mistake:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static int dimension = 1;
        public static int[] junkArray = new int[dimension];

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Method1();
            Method2();
        }

        static void Method1()
        {
            int i = 0;
            junkArray[i] = (int)Math.Floor(-3.0002);
        }

        static void Method2()
        {
            int i = 0;
            int[] junkArray = new int[dimension];
            Console.WriteLine("final: " + (int)junkArray[i] + " test:" + (int)Math.Floor(-3.0002));
        }
    }
}
```

This produces the results you're seeing:

final:0 test:-4

I've split the code into two methods, one method which is doing the "calculation" and another which does the "presentation". However, for some reason (lack of caffeine, whatever) my second method also declares an array variable that is hiding/shadowing the field that contains our computed results. This isn't illegal, but it means that when I read from junkArray in my Console.WriteLine method call I'm reading from a *different* junkArray to the one I wrote my results to earlier.

This may not be what's happening, but it's a possibility and without seeing your actual code it's the best guess I can offer. Have a look and make absolutely sure that the array you're reading from is *definitely* the same array you wrote your results to, rather than a second array that's "shadowing" the first.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things happening here

First - -0.02043936 is a calculated value

Now you are applying math.floor on it. What it will do is, it will floor the value and return a double which will again be a significantly small number.

Now you are casting it to an integer. while doing so, as it is more close to zero, it will turn it out to zero.

To prove this, make the calculated value -0.62043936 or something like and you will get -1 as per your expectation

Comment: Calling Floor() with a value of -0.02043936 will return a double, yes, but that double should be -1. Casting that to an int should then produce -1. I think you may be confusing flooring with rounding.

Comment: You are right about it and the same fact is also given on the msdn here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0b5f0xb.aspx. But I think you should try what I have suggested. It is really an interesting question.

Comment: So you have just argued why `(int) Math.Floor(calculatedValue[i])` should return zero, so why is `test` -1?

Comment: No, not that, your observation is perfectly correct, the thing is, most suspected part of this problem was casting to int. If it is not the culprit, may be we have to dig to code more deeply to find out the reason. I know that the floor of -0.02... should be -1.

Comment: I would further suggest to use double instead of float. Make the calculated value array of type double. This should make the difference.